# Facebook Graph API Test Users Instagram Account Linking Issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-appreview

[image: Issue while connecting instagram account with facebook test user]

I have created a Facebook TestUser for making APP review. The testUser account allowed to create a testPage for testing graphAPI and Login workflow.

I am using instagram search hash tag API so I need to link an businessInstagram account to this testUser but I am facing error in reviewing connection.

I have tried a couple of IG accounts but it does not work for the testUser only.